# Continuous axis for multiple boxplots of duration data with Plotly in Grafana

Tags: javascript, postgresql, plotly, grafana

I'm really out of ideas on how to solve this puzzle, so it has come to this.

I am using the "Plotly panel" panel plugin for Grafana to show multiple boxplots of duration data.
I need to show these boxplots relative to each other like in the image below:

[image]

Using the query below this works fine, the only problem is that the values are in seconds and i want to show them in `YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. Mind you i don't want to show any dates, i want the duration.

Example output:

```js
[
  "9",
  "27",
  "76",
  "3615738"
]
```

```sql
select
  array_agg(duration_/1000 order by duration_ asc),
  name_,
  task_def_key_
from
    act_hi_taskinst
where
  duration_ is not null
  and proc_def_id_ = '$PROCESS_ID'
group by
  task_def_key_, name_
```

When i use the query below the values returned from the query are in the correct format, but the y-axis is not continuous anymore. It's like each boxplot gets it's own graph and they're just put on top of each other.

Example output:

```js
[
  "11 mons 15 days 19:49:44.774",
  "11 mons 15 days 19:51:34.721",
  "1 year 20 days 19:58:33.093",
  "1 year 27 days 21:29:48.734",
  "1 year 27 days 21:30:18.473"
]
```

[image]

```sql
select
  array_agg(age(end_time_, start_time_) order by age(end_time_, start_time_) asc),
  name_,
  task_def_key_
from
    act_hi_taskinst
where
  duration_ is not null
  and proc_def_id_ = '$PROCESS_ID'
group by
  task_def_key_, name_
```

So my question is, how should i adjust my query so that the data can be interpreted by Plotly correctly. Or, how can i format the milliseconds to `YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` with Javascript inside the Plotly panel in Grafana (i don't think i can use any libraries there).

Thanks in advance for any responses guiding me in the right direction.

Comment: [Work in progress] I now create a timestamp (seconds since Jan 1st 1970) from the duration in ms. It's far from ideal as the date 1970/01/01 is visible with every data-point. However it's much more readable than just giving the time in seconds or even minutes, especially for longer duration and the box-plots are shown in correct relation to each other. Will update if/when i find a better workaround.

Comment: Can you share some source code of how you did the integration of Plotly?